# Why is this didSet property not printing any output in Swift?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, didset

I have correctly set up a UIPageViewController.

I would like to check the itemIndex of each views and display content accordingly. Here's what the code looks like:

```
var itemIndex: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if itemIndex == 1 {
            println("Character is Lela!")
        }
        if itemIndex == 0 {
            println("Character is John!")
    }  
  } 
}
```

### What I tried

1. I run the app
2. **Console Output: "Character is John!"**
3. I swipe forward (to the right)
4. **Console Output: "Character is Lela!"**
5. I swipe back (to the left)
6. **There is no output!**
7. I swipe forward
8. **There is no output! Again!**

What is this due to? Here's the full code:

```
import UIKit

var currentIndex: Int = 0
var nextIndex: Int = 0

class ProView: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

let characterImages = ["character1", "character2", "character1", "character2", "character1", "character2", "character1", "character2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()

    character = 1
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// Forward, check if this IS NOT the last controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        // Check if there is another view
        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < characterImages.count {

            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
}


// Check if this IS NOT the first controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex < 0 {

            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < characterImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = characterImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
}

    return nil
}

func createPageViewController() {

    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self
    pageController.delegate = self

    if characterImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return characterImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

return 0
}

// BETA

func pageViewController(PageItemController: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers pageViewController: [AnyObject],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{

    if (!completed)
    {
        // You do nothing because whatever page you thought
        // the book was on before the gesture started is still the correct page
        return;
    }
    // This is where you would know the page number changed and handle it appropriately
    }

}

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageCharacterChoose: UIImageView!

var itemIndex: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if itemIndex == 1 {
            println("Character is Lela!")
        }
        if itemIndex == 0 {
            println("Character is John!")
    }

    }}
var imageName: String = "" {
    didSet {

        if let imageView = imageCharacterChoose {imageCharacterChoose.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageCharacterChoose!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Comment: didset gets triggered when you set a value: itemIndex = 1;
I don't see you use that in your code?

Comment: Thanks @Simon for commenting my question! That is a good point! Are there other ways to check the itemIndex of the pageController then? Thanks!

Comment: Just get the index by `myPageController.itemIndex`.

Comment: @Simon answer my question with that comment and I'd be glad to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @CeceXX, so just to be clear. Your only confusion was that `didSet` is only called when you actually set that value? Also, is the page controller's `itemIndex` what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. "Why is this didSet property not printing any output in Swift?" and the question in my answer was "What is this due to?", @Simon basically solved my question saying I didn't use the DidSet property correctly. Thank you. I still haven't solved the `itemIndex` issue but that's ok.

Comment: @CeceXX Im glad I could help, what problem with itemIndex isnt solved yet?

Comment: I didn't know how to get the itemIndex of the current pageViewController but I fixed my issue using an alternative way and I'm doing okay now. Thanks for asking and for answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didSet` and `willSet` will only get called when you change the value of the corresponding variable, so in your case you should somewhere in your code do `itemIndex = 1`, or some other value to trigger the functions.